# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "complex_conv2d" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (None, 2, 288)

Tags: conv-neural-network, complex-numbers

I am working with a complex convolutional neural network and my dataset is complex IQ signal data. I am trying to run the following code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from cvnn import *
import cvnn.layers as complex_layers
import tensorflow as tf


def createSB_modrelu():
inputs = complex_layers.complex_input((2, 288))
c0 = complex_layers.ComplexConv2D(32, activation='cart_relu', kernel_size=3)(inputs)
c1 = complex_layers.ComplexConv2D(32, activation='cart_relu', kernel_size=3)(c0)
c2 = complex_layers.ComplexMaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='valid')(c1)
t01 = complex_layers.ComplexConv2DTranspose(5, kernel_size=2, strides=(2, 2), activation='cart_relu')(c2)
concat01 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate(\[t01, c1\], axis=-1)
c3 = complex_layers.ComplexConv2D(4, activation='cart_relu', kernel_size=3)(concat01)
out = complex_layers.ComplexConv2D(4, activation='cart_relu', kernel_size=3)(c3)
return tf.keras.Model(inputs, out)
```

I am getting this error!! Can anyone help me?

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "complex_conv2d" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (None, 2, 288)
```

Comment: More curious about which kind of data has a shape such as that

Comment: Here is the dataset: [link](https://mailuc-my.sharepoint.com/personal/wang2ba_ucmail_uc_edu/_layouts/15/onedrive.aspx?id=%2Fpersonal%2Fwang2ba%5Fucmail%5Fuc%5Fedu%2FDocuments%2Fgroup%2Fdatasets%5Fpublic%2FHackRF10%5Fdataset%5Fcns22&ga=1)